# Using tidyverse to select levels from one column that are filtered from another

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a dataset that contains replicated rows that are errors and to remove them. I have managed to do so in another way but seeing the power of tidyverse, I would like to try to do so using that package.

the table I work with consists of abondance data of 4 species at 3 sites (1,2,3) and each site is divided into sections (here 1 to 5). There can only be one visit per date which mean that if there are duplicates (several visit_id for the same site, date, and section) they are errors to be removed.

How I do wish to remove these duplicated is as follows:

- if there is more that one level of visit_id for a site and date:
- if for visit_id i, at least one of the row contains a value in the column total, I want to keep for that date and site, all the rows that correspond to that visit_id level.
- if for visit_id i, all rows contains NA (because none of the species was observed at that specific date and site), keep the first visit_id level (first or last, does not matter, but I only want to keep one level)
  -else (there is only one visit_id), do nothing.

here are the data:

```
dat<- data.frame(matrix(c(1,800681,1,"25-07-10",1,0,0,0,1,
             1,800681,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800681,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800682,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800682,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800682,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800683,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800683,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800683,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800684,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800684,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800684,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800685,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800685,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             1,800685,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800681,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800681,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800682,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800682,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800683,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800683,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800684,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800684,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800685,1,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             2,800685,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             3,800681,1,"25-07-10",1,0,0,0,1,
             3,800682,2,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             3,800683,3,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             3,800684,4,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             3,800685,5,"25-07-10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), ncol=9,nrow = 30,byrow = T))

colnames(dat)=c("site","visit_id","section","visit_date","species1","species2","species3","species4","tot")
```

I played around with filter(if) and slice but I cannot manage to nest my different requests. Any suggestions would be very welcome

the final result I would like to get is:

```
dat<- data.frame(matrix(c(1,800681,1,25-07-10,1,0,0,0,1,
1,800681,2,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
1,800681,3,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
2,800681,1,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
2,800681,2,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
3,800681,1,25-07-10,1,0,0,0,1,
3,800682,2,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
3,800683,3,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
3,800684,4,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
3,800685,5,25-07-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), ncol=9,nrow = 10,byrow = T))

colnames(dat)<-c("site","visit_id","section","visit_date","species1","species2","species3","species4","tot")
```

I do not manage to imbricate these two operations. Here is what I have done:
list_visit_id=as.vector(unique(dat$visit_id[!is.na(dat$tot)]))

here I just select the observations without error:

`heredat1=dat %>% group_by(site,visit_date,section)%>%
            filter(length(visit_id)<2)`

below I select, among the replicated row only 1 for which observation data are available:

`dat3=dat %>% group_by(site,visit_date,section)%>%
  filter(length(visit_id)>1,visit_id %in% list_visit_id)`

Comment: Could you post what you expect this to look like? Like a final result. I want to make sure I show you the correct response.

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: would `dat %>%
  group_by(site, visit_date, section) %>%
  slice(1)` give you what you want?

Comment: no, I indeed tried that but this grouping does not remove the duplicated rows because they are all unique. Further, using slice(1) you would keep the first row while I do not necessarily want to make that choice.

Comment: What you could do is create three reference logical vectors for whether each variable is unique in the whole dataset, and then use two nested `ifelse()` calls within `filter()` that would sequentially go through `visit_id`, `section`, then `site`

Comment: I have edited my question trying to follow the suggestion from Graeme Frost but I cannot figure out how to imbricate these 2 operations